# Unable to cast object of type 'X' to type 'X'

Tags: c#, json, windows-phone-7, parsing, windows-phone-8

I'm trying to parse a JSON file for a Windows Phone app, and my current code is:

```
 private void Button1_Tap(object sender, System.Windows.Input.GestureEventArgs e)
    {
        Button1.FontSize = 15;
        Button1.Content = "Fetching...";
        var client = new WebClient();
        client.OpenReadCompleted +=
            (s, eargs) =>
            {
                var serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(RootObject));
                if (eargs.Error != null)
                {
                    if (eargs.Error.Message.Contains("NotFound"))
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Could not retrieve playlist", "Error", MessageBoxButton.OK);
                        Button1.Content = "Could not retrieve playlist";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Could not retrieve playlist", "Error", MessageBoxButton.OK);
                        Button1.Content = "Could not retrieve playlist";
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    var songHistory = (station1)serializer.ReadObject(eargs.Result);
                    Button1.Content = songHistory.text;
                }
            };
        var uri = new Uri("<JSONGOESHERE>");
        client.OpenReadAsync(uri);
    }

    public class station1
    {
        public string station { get; set; }
        public string title { get; set; }
        public string artist { get; set; }
        public string text { get; set; }
    }

    public class station2
    {
        public string station { get; set; }
        public int listeners { get; set; }
        public string title { get; set; }
        public string artist { get; set; }
        public string text { get; set; }
    }

    public class station3
    {
        public string station { get; set; }
        public int listeners { get; set; }
        public string title { get; set; }
        public string artist { get; set; }
        public string text { get; set; }
    }

    public class RootObject
    {
        public station1 station1 { get; set; }
        public station2 station2 { get; set; }
        public station3 station3 { get; set; }
    }
```

I require the same fetching of text for "station2" and "station3" later as well, which is why I've left them in.

Currently, what happens is I am getting the following error when I run this on the line

```
var songHistory = (station1)serializer.ReadObject(eargs.Result);
```

InvalidCastException was unhandled by user code
An exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException' occurred in APP.DLL but was not handled in user code
Unable to cast object of type 'RootObject' to type 'station1'.

I had used the json2csharp generator to create the above so I'm not sure what's wrong.

Any help would be awesome.

Comment: Is it `lunaradio` or `station1`? And what's `LunaRootObject` vs `RootObject`? Your question is inconsistent...

Comment: Made a mistake in the question, it is `station1`, and `RootObject`. Question edited. Sorry, and thanks!

Comment: You created a serializer for `RootObject`. Why are expecting the output of the `ReadObject` to be of type `station1`? It is of type `RootObject` as the exception states.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You created a serializer for the type `RootObject`. So the output of `ReadObject` is that type. Just cast it correctly (there is no generic overload for `ReadObject`):

```
var root = (RootObject)serializer.ReadObject(eargs.Result);
var songHistory = root.station1;
```

Comment: Ah, this looks more correct than mine. Using this, I'm getting a NullReferenceException, though. it would appear that `root` and `songHistory` remain null. Any ideas?

Comment: @reignofcomputer: that doesn't make sense. If `ReadObject` returned null then the cast to station1 would have succeeded and you would have seen that with your code. Maybe the callback is being invoked multiple times. Put in a null check and see what happens.

Comment: Finally found time to look at this a little more, I'm told that "The DataContractJsonSerializer cannot match property "1" from the json object to the property `station1` on the `RootObject` class.". My JSON file is here: [http://www.reignofcomputer.com/tmpsend/nowplaying.json](http://www.reignofcomputer.com/tmpsend/nowplaying.json), not sure what to do next.

Comment: @ReignOfComputer Your json does not seem to correspond to the classes you have defined, but I don't know exactly what they should look like. You should probably ask another question.

Comment: Will do, guess this question has been answered anyway. Time for another. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the method doesn't also have to take a Type as a parameter for deserialization?

```
var songHistory = (station1)serializer.ReadObject(eargs.Result, typeof(station1));
```

Or maybe it has a generic overload that does the deserialization and returns a T directly?

```
var songHistory = serializer.ReadObject<station1>(eargs.Result);
```